# Recover a lost IBM DS4300 SAN password?

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm, password-recovery

I have a pair of IBM DS4300 SAN units that I need to perform a firmware upgrade on. Unfortunately the admin passwords on these units have been lost and now need to be reset. I had hoped the default password of 'infiniti' would work but it seems that it must have been changed.

I know the method here is to contact IBM but the cost of that phone call is ludicrous if someone out here knows what they're going to tell me to do.  These units are out of warranty and the cost of support is beyond what we have the budget for.  Is there an interrupt I can enter during the boot process (similar to a cisco password recovery) or is there a hardware/software tool I require?  Please, if anyone has ever gone through the process of an IBM password recovery I’m asking for a little help.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the password I need to reset is the one used for serial cable access and not for storage manager.  Sorry if I have caused more confusion.

Comment: Just to clarify: "infiniti" is the default password for the serial cable access; you are asking about Storage Manager password, which is a different thing. The latter is empty by default.

Comment: Thanks kubanskamac, it's actually the serial cable access password I'm asking about though.  I'm sorry if my question appeared vague, I shall attempt to edit it to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the default password for the Storage Manager is 'config'